# How can i change variables every 5 sec so that the next ball behaves different than the previous? And how can i add multiple balls?

Tags: javascript, html, class, canvas

How can i add several balls to the same canvas, using the same class, but change its values every time? e.g First a blue ball that moves to the right, and then 5 sec later, spawn a red ball that moves another direction. And how can i store all these balls in an array?

I have tried just repeating the "new Ball(...)" with the same variables as the previous, where each variable contains a random number, thinking they would change that random value each time i create a new ball from that class. But nothing happens, or i think it just creates a new ball exactly the same and on top of the last. I have also tried this, just with a function that repeats every 5 sec, but same result.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Ballgame</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<style>
    canvas{
        background-color: lightgrey;
        outline:2px solid black;
        margin-top:20;
    }
    div{
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        background-color: red;
        margin: 100px auto;

    }

</style>
<body>
    <center>
        <canvas id="canvas" height="600" width="800"></canvas>
    </center>
    <audio src="Media/bounce.mp3">


<script>
    "use strict"



        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");




        var bounce = document.querySelector("audio")
        var color;
        var radius;
        var posNeg = [-1,1]
        var speedx = 5 * posNeg[Math.floor(Math.random()*2)];
        var speedy = 3 * posNeg[Math.floor(Math.random()*2)];
        var randomx = Math.floor(Math.random()*700 +50)
        var randomy = Math.floor(Math.random()*500 +50)
    class Ball{
        constructor(x, y, speedx,speedy, radius, color){
            color = "hsla(" + Math.floor(Math.random()*360+1) +  ", 100%, 50%, 1)";
            radius = Math.floor(Math.random()*30 +2);
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.speedx = speedx;   
            this.speedy = speedy;
            this.radius = radius
            this.color = color
        }


        draw(){
            canvasContext.beginPath ();
            canvasContext.arc(this.x,this.y,this.radius,0,Math.PI *2);
            canvasContext.strokeStyle = "black";
            canvasContext.lineWidth = 5;
            canvasContext.stroke();
            canvasContext.fillStyle = this.color;
            canvasContext.fill();
            canvasContext.closePath();
        }

        move(){
            this.x += this.speedx;
            this.y += this.speedy;
            if(this.x - this.radius < 0 || this.x +this.radius > canvas.width){
                this.speedx = -1 * this.speedx;
                bounce.play()
            }
            if(this.y - this.radius < 0 || this.y + this.radius > canvas.height){
                this.speedy = -1 * this.speedy;
                bounce.play()
            }
        }
    }
    var ball = new Ball(randomx, randomy, speedx, speedy, radius, color)

    function animate(){
        canvasContext.clearRect (0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ball.move();
        ball.draw();
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
    setInterval(function(){
        new Ball(randomx, randomy, speedx, speedy, radius, color);
    }, 5000)
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

As i said earlier, I think it just prints a new ball that is exactly the same as, and on top the previous ball. Hence i cant see any difference. I want it to create a new ball but with different values e.g different color, radius, and direction.

Comment: In your `animate` you still animate the very one `ball`. If you want multiple balls, have the array and iterate over the array in the `animate`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code the `randomX` and the other vars never change. That's why it's always the same ball.